# Doubt on Motional EMF

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

In motional EMF of a rod of resistance r connected with resistance R  moved with velocity v is it equivalent to 
1) battery, r and R all connected in parallel.
2) all in series .
? 
I think it should be 1) as V will be the potential across the rod but have seen questions considering it as latter. 
[image]

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Wait I'll add a figure then.

Comment: Please add the references as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose our setup looks like this:

[image: Sliding rod]

where $r$ is the resistance between the ends of the rod and $R$ is the external resistance. You don't specify which direction the field is in so I've arbitrarily chosen it to be going into the page.

The motion of the rod at a velocity $\mathbf v$ causes a Lorentz force $\mathbf F_e = -e\mathbf v \times \mathbf B$ on the electrons in the rod, so the force on the electrons points downwards:

[image: Force on electrons]

So the electrons will travel round the circuit like this:

[image: Motion of electrons]

Note that the electrons flow in series through the rod then through the external resistance $R$ then back into the rod again, so the equivalent circuit looks like this:

[image: Equivalent circuit]